# Server not found error in swagger

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, swagger

I just started using swagger to interface with my sample rest web service which I have hosted in my local host apache tomcat listening to 8089 port. The issue that I'm facing is that whenever I try to access my application from swagger I'm getting the error "**ERROR Server not found or an error occurred**" but Im able to access this service and get the data from a regular browser request. Screen shot of my swagger application is given below.
[image: Image of my swagger editor and the code]

The code for my service is given below.

```
   @GET
   @Path("/users")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(){
      return userDao.getAllUsers();
   }
```

The screen shot for the regular request from the browser is given below.
[image: Screen shot of request to web service via browser]
If my understanding is correct there nothing wrong with my web service, it is the swagger API that is not working since the browser request works. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it. Please let me know if you require any other information.

Answer (score -1):

I find your screenshot suggests that this is a cross-domain calls，Maybe you can try to modify "localhost: 8089" host configuration, make it become a specific IP address.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work, I gave the IP of the localhost as 127.0.0.1:8089